# OBD2 to bluetooth adaptor for 2001 Renault?

Tags: tools, obd-ii

I have a 2001 Renault Clio 2 1.6 16V (French made) and I'm looking for a OBD2 to bluetooth adaptor to read computer's parameters. There are MANY available with all price ranges, but I'm not sure what to pick for my car.

I'd like to use my Android device to pick up the readings.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Edit: now doing some reseach i found there is also an European standard, EOBD! More puzzled than before!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this solution](http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/car/e661/) at ThinkGeek. It plugs in to your OBDII port, . It connects via Bluetooth, and works with several different apps from the Android market. HTH!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of favorable reviews on the [ELM327 on DealExtreme](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/elm327-bluetooth-obd-ii-wireless-transceiver-dongle-16921).  $52.99 currently...

[image: ELM327 Bluetooth OBD-II Dongle]

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are looking for a Android solution so I am going to send you to an iPhone site.  Actually, they have a nice list of hardware there which is open enough that they can support it as a third party.  You can find Andriod software for any of these devices. You may also have to click on the hardware tab since the deep link does not seem to work.

[DevToaster Rev](http://www.devtoaster.com/products/rev/)

You might want to look at the ElmCanII-WLAN dongle, it is WiFi and not Bluetooth but it also mentions EOBD support.

**Edit:**  Here is a [Bluetooth module](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004VXSH48) that specifically mentions that it is Android compatible. It looks inexpensive as well.